# For each individual user, I want to use their /home/ directory for Ansible credentials

Tags: ansible, lookup

I'm working in a multi user environment. I want to have some accountability of who ran which plays. So we can't have a common `group_vars/all` that contains ansible login credentials. I'm not wanting to force my users to use extra vars at the command line for ansible credentials either.

Ideally I'd like to have each user have a specific file off of their `/home/user_name/` directory where they set their ansible credentials (I'll use `ansible_info.yml` so we have something specific to talk about). This would provide me security, as other users not be able to access another users home directory.

Off of the `/home/user_name/`, would I have to get each user to create a "all" file (as ansible by default looks for a "all" file)? Or could I use a different name for this file (`ansible_info.yml`)? The contents of the `all/ansible_info.yml` would be:

```
ansible_user: end_user_ssh_username

ansible_ssh_pass: end_user_ssh_username_password

ansible_become: yes

ansible_become_user: service_account_name

ansible_become_pass: service_account_name_password
```

To grab the user_name of who SSH'ed onto the server, I can use any of the three below commands:

```
command: whoami
{{ lookup('env','USER') }}
command: id -un
```

After one of the above commands has been run, then I register the variable.
`register: logged_in_user`

Then I'm a little stuck on what to do next for supplying the rest of the ansible credentials.

Do I use vars_files?

```
   vars_files:
     - /home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_info.yml
```

Or in the play should do I need to state the all of the ansible credentials as variables that refer to the `/home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_info.yml` file?

Or using "lookup" create an individual file for each Ansible credential that I'm looking for, as I've shown below:
vars:

```
ansible_user: "{{lookup('file', '/home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_user.yml')}}"
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{lookup('file', '/home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_ssh_pass')}}"
ansible_become_user: "{{lookup('file', '/home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_become_user.yml')}}"
ansible_become_pass: "{{lookup('file', '/home/{{ logged_in_user }}/ansible_become_pass')}}"
```

Comment: Have you tried any of your ideas? And why not use `~` alias as home directory path?

Comment: I'm able to get the username. But when I do debug, I can see extra things (stdout_lines & stderr_lines).


[WARNING]: Unable to find '/home/{'stderr_lines'
'stdout_lines': [u'chris']}/ansible_user.yml'


Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /home/{'stderr_lines': [], u'changed':  u'stdout':  'stdout_lines': [u'chris']}/ansible_user.yml"}


To get rid of the extra stuff. I might be able to use "trim". 
Or when I am defining the logged in user, I need to define the variable with .stdout on the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is was I wrote to get this to pull data from my files. Next I'll see if I can authenticate with it. 
Basically what was messing me up was the extra characters from "stdout", so I just made an extra variable to put the results into, and it work.

---

- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: get the username running the deploy

  local_action: command whoami

  register: whoami_results

  - name: show the output of the home_directory results

  vars:

  whoami_results_stdout: "{{whoami_results.stdout}}"

  home_directory: /home/{{ whoami_results_stdout }}

  ansible_user: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ home_directory }}/ansible_user.yml') }}"

  ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ home_directory }}/ansible_ssh_pass.yml') }}"

  ansible_become: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ home_directory }}/ansible_become.yml') }}"

  ansible_become_user: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ home_directory }}/ansible_become_user.yml') }}"

  ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ home_directory }}/ansible_become_pass.yml') }}"

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked this again, and found a much better solution. I made the contents of group_vars/all become this.

```
ansible_user: "{{ lookup('file', '~/ansible_user') }}"
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ lookup('file', '~/ansible_ssh_pass') }}"
ansible_become: "{{ lookup('file', '~/ansible_become') }}"
ansible_become_user: "{{ lookup('file', '~/ansible_become_user') }}"
ansible_become_pass: "{{ lookup('file', '~/ansible_become_pass') }}"
```

Then we are going to have the end users just have the corresponding files off of their /home/. The end user will need to update these files when they have to update their Active Directory password though (minor issue). The files off of their home directory work with ansible-vault.